# Может ли ОС менять ядро на котором выполняется поток?

Tags: python, linux, windows, многопоточность, macos

Представим, что я написал программу на python и использую многопоточность. Изначально мой поток ОС расположила на каком-то ядре, может ли она в будущем, при переключении потоков или освобождении ресурсов, поменять ядро на котором находится поток?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё верно, операционная система может переместить поток на другое ядро в процессе выполнения программы. Это происходит если система понимает что другое ядро менее загружено и/или сможет выполнить там операцию быстрее.
Операционная система управляет планированием потоков и принимает решения какой поток выполнится на каком ядре в каждый момент времени.

Answer (score 4):

Да, может менять и делает это, но этот процесс на многих ОС можно ограничить с помощью такой штуки как [Processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity).

> **Processor affinity**, or **CPU pinning** or "cache affinity", **enables the
> binding and unbinding of a process or a thread to a central processing
> unit (CPU) or a range of CPUs**, so that the process or thread will
> execute only on the designated CPU or CPUs rather than any CPU. This
> can be viewed as a modification of the native central queue scheduling
> algorithm in a symmetric multiprocessing operating system. Each item
> in the queue has a tag indicating its kin processor. At the time of
> resource allocation, each task is allocated to its kin processor in
> preference to others.

В данном случае под `CPU` имеются в виду ядра процессора. Я помню во времена игры в старый ещё `Counter Strike` некоторые в винде делали ему привязку к конкретному ядру процессора, так вроде бы меньше были лаги в теории.